# Get last attribute value in XML using Linq

Tags: xml, linq, linq-to-xml, xml-attribute

My XML file look like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<dskh>
  <khachhang maso="kh01">
    <ten_kh>nhi</ten_kh>
    <tuoi_kh>15</tuoi_kh>
    <dchi_kh>dt</dchi_kh>
  </khachhang>

  <khachhang maso="kh02">
    <ten_kh>hung</ten_kh>
    <tuoi_kh>15</tuoi_kh>
    <dchi_kh>hcm</dchi_kh>
  </khachhang>
</dskh>
```

I want to get last attribute value of **khachhang** element. In this case is **maso="kh02"**. Because i want when i insert new **khachhang** element, **maso** attribute will increase auto. Someone can advice me some good ...Thank everyone so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var xdoc = XDocument.Load(path_to_xml);
var result = (string)xdoc.XPathSelectElement("//khachhang[last()]")
                         .Attribute("maso");
```

Or

```
var result = (string)xdoc.Descendants("khachhang").Last()
                         .Attribute("maso");
```

Also if it is possible that no `khachhang` elements will be in your xml, you should try to get last element. And then get attribute if `khachhang` element was found:

```
var lastKhachhang = xdoc.Descendants("khachhang").LastOrDefault();
if (lastKhachhang == null)
    // use default maso value
else
   maso = (string)lastKhachhang.Attribute("maso");
```

It's important to use `LastOrDefault` in this case. Otherwise you'll get an exception.

Comment: What about **maso** auto increase, can you help me?

Comment: when i learn Linq to XML..I see this code:

    var q = from c in loaded.Descendants("contact")
        where (int)c.Attribute("contactId") < 4
        select (string)c.Element("firstName") + “ “ +
      (string)c.Element("lastName");

how can i write like here bro:

     var q = from c in xmlSource.contact
        where c.contactId < 4
        select c.firstName + " " + c.lastName;

Comment: @user1621647 sorry, didn't get what you are trying to do. First sample is Linq to Xml. Second is something else (possibly Linq to Objects)

Comment: can you explain me what's different between last and lastordefault method?

Comment: @user1621647 sure, if sequence does not contain elements, then `Last()` will throw an exception. `LastOrDefault()` in this case will just return default value for sequence element type (null for XElement). So, if there is no `khachhang` elements (i.e. before you will add first one), you will get exception with `Last()` method

Comment: hi bro, i want encrypt and hide xml source file. What should i do?

Comment: when i decrypt xml file, it through exception: Bad Data. What does it mean, bro?

Comment: @user1621647 sorry, I'm kind of busy now. You can ask a question on SO :)

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively

```
var xdoc = XDocument.Load(path_to_xml);
var lastElement = xdoc.Root.Elements("khachhang").Last();
var value = lastElement.Attribute("maso").Value;
```

Note I always put null checks in between accessing an element or attributes value that I have just read, just in case.